# What are the upsides and downsides if one's currency exchange order is routed as an odd lot order instead of IdealPro on Interactive Brokers?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, interactive-brokers

I placed a currency exchange order on Interactive Brokers from EUR to USD. Since the amount was below 20kEUR, Interactive Brokers told me that the currency exchange order would be routed as an odd lot order instead of IdealPro.

What are the upsides and downsides if one's currency exchange order is routed as an odd lot order instead of IdealPro?

---

Message from Interactive Brokers:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reddit user [Terrigible](https://www.reddit.com/user/Terrigible) [mentioned](https://redd.it/168hm3a) one downside if one's currency exchange order is routed as an odd lot order instead of IdealPro on Interactive Brokers: the exchange rate is slightly below the market rate.

> Odd lot orders execute 1-2 pips outside the quoted spread.

Reddit user [major_domo](https://www.reddit.com/user/major_domo) [pointed me](https://redd.it/168hm3a) to the [official IBKR reference](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/lib/cstools/faq/#/content/65996956) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20230904001202/https://www.interactivebrokers.com/lib/cstools/faq/#/content/65996956)):

> Odd lot marketable limit orders will still be accepted, but they are not guaranteed execution at the inter-bank spreads afforded to IdealPro orders, and **will generally be executed at slightly inferior prices ranging from 1- 2 basis points outside the IdealPro quote**. Also, an Odd Lot order may take longer to get filled. The IdealPro Minimum and Maximum Forex order sizes can be found on the Interactive Brokers website.